# Dynamic assignment of unique values - Python

Tags: python, pandas, logic

I am trying to assign unique values to a specific allocation or group. What makes it tricky is these unique values are dynamically starting and finishing. So the groups will be holding previously seen values and taking new unique values at various time periods. In regards to the `df`, unique values are located in `Place` and the groups to pick from are found in `Available Group` for each period of time `Period`.

The broad guidelines I'm trying to adhere to is:

1) Each `Group` can hold no more than 3 unique `Places` **at any one time**

2) Current unique `Places` should be evenly distributed across each `Group`

3) Once `Places` get assigned to `Group`, keep until `Group` finishes. **Unless `Group` becomes NA or uneven allocation of meetings**

To understand how many `Places` are currently occuring I've included `Total`, which is based on if the `Place` value appears again. I'm meeting my first two guidelines and partially the third. When a `Place` is assigned to a `Group` it is held at the same `Group` until the `Place` is finished (does not appear again).

However, I'm not referencing `Available Group` to understand if that `Group` is available. When the `Group` becomes unavailable I'd like to rearrange those `Places` across the other `Available Group`. Using the `df` below, the assigning of places works well the unique places increases. But as soon as they start to finish and Group 2 becomes unavailable those places arent re-assigned to group 1. At this point there are only 3 places occurring.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Period' : [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6],  
    'Place' : ['CLUB','CLUB','CLUB','HOME','HOME','AWAY','AWAY','WORK','WORK','AWAY','AWAY','GOLF','GOLF','CLUB','CLUB','POOL','POOL','HOME','HOME','WORK','WORK','AWAY','AWAY','POOL','POOL','TENNIS','TENNIS'],                                
    'Total' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5],                            
    'Available Group' : ['1','2','1','2','1','2','1','2','1','1','2','1','2','2','1','2','1','2','1','2','1','1','2','1','2','2','1'],                           
    })
```

Attempt:

```
# df to store all unique places
uniquePlaces = pd.DataFrame(df["Place"].unique(), columns=["Place"])

# Start stores index of df where the place appears 1st
uniquePlaces["Start"] = -1

# End stores index of df where the place appears last 
uniquePlaces["End"] = -1

def assign_place_label(group):

    ''' Create a label column that calculates the amount of unique meetings 
        throughout the racing schedule '''

    label = uniquePlaces[uniquePlaces["Place"] == group.name].index[0]
    group["Place Label"] = label
    uniquePlaces.loc[label, "Start"] = group.index.min()
    uniquePlaces.loc[label, "End"] = group.index.max()
    return group

# Based on Start and End of each place, assign index to each place.
# when 'freed' the index is reused to new place appearing after that
def Assign_Meetings_group(up):
    up["Index"] = 0
    up["Freed"] = False
    max_ind=0
    free_indx = []
    for i in range(len(up)):
        ind_freed = up.index[(up["End"]<up.iloc[i]["Start"]) & (~up["Freed"])]

        free = list(up.loc[ind_freed, "Index"])
        free_indx += free

        up.loc[ind_freed, "Freed"] = True

        if len(free_indx)>0:
            m = min(free_indx)
            up.loc[i, "Index"] = m
            free_indx.remove(m)

        else:
            up.loc[i, "Index"] = max_ind
            max_ind+=1

    up["Group"] = up["Index"]//3+1

    return up  

df2 = df.groupby("Place").apply(assign_place_label)
uniquePlaces = Assign_Meetings_group(uniquePlaces)

df3 = df2[df2['Period']!=0].drop_duplicates(subset = ['Period','Place'])
result = df3.merge(uniquePlaces[["Group"]], how="left", left_on="Place Label", right_index=True, sort=False)
```

Out:

```
    Period Place  Total Available Group  Place Label  Group
0   1       CLUB  1      1               0            1    
1   2       CLUB  1      1               0            1    
3   2       HOME  2      1               1            1    
5   2       AWAY  3      1               2            1    
7   3       WORK  4      1               3            2    
9   3       AWAY  4      1               2            1    
11  3       GOLF  5      1               4            2    
13  3       HOME  5      1               1            1    
15  4       CLUB  4      1               0            1    
17  4       AWAY  3      1               2            1    
19  4       POOL  3      1               5            1    
21  5       WORK  3      1               3            2    
23  5       POOL  2      1               5            1    
25  6       GOLF  1      1               4            2
```

Intended Output:

```
    Period Place  Total Available Group  Place Label  Group
0   1       CLUB  1      1               0            1    
1   2       CLUB  1      1               0            1    
3   2       HOME  2      1               1            1    
5   2       AWAY  3      1               2            1    
7   3       WORK  4      1               3            2    
9   3       AWAY  4      1               2            1    
11  3       GOLF  5      1               4            2    
13  3       HOME  5      1               1            1    
15  4       CLUB  4      1               0            1    
17  4       AWAY  3      1               2            1    
19  4       POOL  3      1               5            1    
21  5       WORK  3      1               3            1    
23  5       POOL  2      1               5            1    
25  6       GOLF  1      1               4            1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution for the question, please find the detail in comment

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Period' : [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6],  
    'Place' : ['CLUB','CLUB','CLUB','HOME','HOME','AWAY','AWAY','WORK','WORK','AWAY','AWAY','GOLF','GOLF','CLUB','CLUB','POOL','POOL','HOME','HOME','WORK','WORK','AWAY','AWAY','POOL','POOL','TENNIS','TENNIS'],                                
    'Total' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5],                            
    'Available Group' : ['1','2','1','2','1','2','1','2','1','1','2','1','2','2','1','2','1','2','1','2','1','1','2','1','2','2','1'],                           
    })

# df to store all unique places
uniquePlaces = pd.DataFrame(df["Place"].unique(), columns=["Place"])

# Start stores index of df where the place appears 1st
uniquePlaces["Start"] = -1

# End stores index of df where the place appears last 
uniquePlaces["End"] = -1

def assign_place_label(group):

    ''' Create a label column that calculates the amount of unique meetings 
        throughout the racing schedule '''

    label = uniquePlaces[uniquePlaces["Place"] == group.name].index[0]
    group["Place Label"] = label
    uniquePlaces.loc[label, "Start"] = group.index.min()
    uniquePlaces.loc[label, "End"] = group.index.max()+1
    return group

df2 = df.groupby("Place").apply(assign_place_label)


def calc_groups(uniquePlaces, df2):

    ## group need to be changed only when a group starts or finishes
    change_points = np.sort(uniquePlaces[["Start", "End"]].values.ravel()).reshape(-1,1)

    ## for each change points find boolean indxes for places (True if place is in use at that point)
    inds = (change_points>=uniquePlaces["Start"].values) & (change_points<uniquePlaces["End"].values)

    ## all available indexes for place
    all_ind = set(uniquePlaces.index.values+1)
    prev_ind = np.array([0]*len(all_ind))

    result = []
    for ind in inds:
        ## copy prev_ind where place exists
        new_ind = prev_ind * ind
        ## mark places with index greater than available places with -1
        new_ind[new_ind>sum(ind)] = -1
        ## mark existing places with index 0 with -1
        new_ind[(new_ind==0) & ind] = -1

        available_ind = all_ind - set(new_ind[new_ind>0])

        ## replace indxes marked by -1 with minimum values from available_ind
        for i in range(len(new_ind)):
            if new_ind[i]==-1:
                new_ind[i] = min(available_ind)
                available_ind.remove(new_ind[i])

        result.append(new_ind)
        prev_ind = new_ind

    result = np.r_[result]
    repeats = np.r_[change_points[1:] - change_points[:-1], [[0]]].ravel()

    ## place index calculated only for change points, now fill the gap between change points
    ## by repeating index in the gap
    result = np.repeat(result, repeats, axis=0)

    df2["group"] = (result[np.arange(len(result)), df2["Place Label"].values]-1)//3 + 1
    return df2


df2 = calc_groups(uniquePlaces, df2)
df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['Period','Place'])
```

**Result**

```
Period   Place  Total Available Group  Place Label  group
0        1    CLUB      1               1            0      1
1        2    CLUB      1               2            0      1
3        2    HOME      2               2            1      1
5        2    AWAY      3               2            2      1
7        3    WORK      4               2            3      2
9        3    AWAY      4               1            2      1
11       3    GOLF      5               1            4      2
13       4    CLUB      4               2            0      1
15       4    POOL      4               2            5      1
17       4    HOME      4               2            1      1
19       5    WORK      4               2            3      1
21       5    AWAY      4               1            2      1
23       5    POOL      4               1            5      1
25       6  TENNIS      5               2            6      1
```